# Android dependency 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer' has different version for the compile (r2.1.0) and runtime (2.9.1) classpath

Tags: android, react-native, exoplayer, react-native-video

I used these two modules(`react-native-video & react-native-nyt-360-video`) in my app:

**package.json:**

```
...
"dependencies": {    
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.5",
    "react-native-nyt-360-video": "1.0.2",
    "react-native-video": "^4.4.1"  
    ...
},
```

**app/build.gradle:**

```
...
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation project(':react-native-video')
    implementation project(':react-native-nyt-360-video')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

I need to have these two modules together becouse my app must play both common and 360 videos.

Now when i run project ( `react-native run-android` ) i encountered with this error:

```
...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer' has different version for the compile (r2.1.0) and runtime (2.9.1) classpath. 
You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

...
```

What i should do? please help me . Thankes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run > **gradlew androidDependencies** command. Using control + F you can look for the conflicting sub-dependencies and thus discover which direct dependency it belongs to.